# Number of pages in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm creating a leaflet and I use the leaflet package. I want to insert an image that fills 2 pages. Is there any option to set 3 separate pages for the front side of the paper and 2 (1 small, 1 double sized) pages for the back? I read through the documentation but I seem to have missed the part where the number of pages is set up. I read that up to 6 are possible. So I guess that fewer pages  is also an option.

I want the front side to look like this

[image]

and the back side like this

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{leaflet}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{biolinum} 
\renewcommand\rmdefault{\sfdefault}% Verwende serifenlose Schrift 
\usepackage{mwe}% Dummy Bilder 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\AddToBackground{1}{\put(0,0){\textcolor{blue!20}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}%     Farbiger Hintergrund für 1. Seite 
\begin{document} 
\title{Veranstalung} 
\author{Veranstalter} 
\date{Veranstaltungstag} 
\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{empty}% Keine Seitenzahlen 
\clearpage 
\section{Willkommen} 
\blindtext 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \clearpage 
\section{Programm}
 \begin{description} 
\item[Mo.\ 31.03.\ 08:00--16:00] 
\blindtext 
\item[Di.\ 01.04.\ 16:00--19:00] 
\blindtext 
\item[Mi.\ 02.04.\ 10:00--22:00] 
\blindtext \item[Do.\ 03.04.\ 10:00--18:00] 
\blindtext \item[Fr.\ 04.04.\ 10:00--12:00] 
\blindtext 
\end{description} 
\clearpage 
\section{Danksagung} Ich danke mir! 
\blindtext
 \end{document}
```

Source: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5663/flyer-din-lang-hoch-mit-6-spalten/5665

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought a MWE wouldn't be necessary since I thought of my issue as a general question rather than a specific problem related to my code. Anyway I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: That would mean anyway that you leaf the effort to users here if you would not have provided a MWE, regardless whether generic or not

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks! Although I'm around for some time here I'm still getting used to how things are done around here.

Comment: Please get the line wrappings right in your MWE ;-)

Comment: afaik, leaflet works by dividing the document in six pages and then doing the imposition on the fly. I fear you will have to modify leaflet's guts to tell it to make five pages, and redo the imposition yourself.

Comment: @Lusr56 Would there be any alternative for me that would require less effort? This will be a one time thing for a while and I could just as well do it with word. However I would like to improve on my TeX knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fool `leaflet` into thinking that the final page is empty and that the “Danksagung” is double column:

```
\documentclass{leaflet}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{biolinum} 
\renewcommand\rmdefault{\sfdefault}% Verwende serifenlose Schrift 
\usepackage{mwe}% Dummy Bilder 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\AddToBackground{1}{\put(0,0){\textcolor{blue!20}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}%     Farbiger Hintergrund für 1. Seite 
\begin{document} 
\title{Veranstalung} 
\author{Veranstalter} 
\date{Veranstaltungstag} 
\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{empty}% Keine Seitenzahlen 
\clearpage 
\section{Willkommen} 
\blindtext 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \clearpage 
\section{Programm}
 \begin{description} 
\item[Mo.\ 31.03.\ 08:00--16:00] 
\blindtext 
\item[Di.\ 01.04.\ 16:00--19:00] 
\blindtext 
\item[Mi.\ 02.04.\ 10:00--22:00] 
\blindtext \item[Do.\ 03.04.\ 10:00--18:00] 
\blindtext \item[Fr.\ 04.04.\ 10:00--12:00] 
\blindtext 
\end{description} 
\clearpage
\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][s]{2.2\linewidth}
\section{Danksagung} Ich danke mir! 
\blindtext

\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the version for getting the program to span two columns.

```
\documentclass{leaflet}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{biolinum} 
\renewcommand\rmdefault{\sfdefault}% Verwende serifenlose Schrift 
\usepackage{mwe}% Dummy Bilder 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\AddToBackground{1}{\put(0,0){\textcolor{blue!20}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}}%     Farbiger Hintergrund für 1. Seite 
\begin{document} 
\title{Veranstalung} 
\author{Veranstalter} 
\date{Veranstaltungstag} 
\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{empty}% Keine Seitenzahlen 
\clearpage 
\section{Willkommen} 
\blindtext 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \clearpage 
\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\begin{minipage}{2.2\linewidth}
\section{Programm}
 \begin{description} 
\item[Mo.\ 31.03.\ 08:00--16:00] 
\blindtext 
\item[Di.\ 01.04.\ 16:00--19:00] 
\blindtext 
\item[Mi.\ 02.04.\ 10:00--22:00] 
\blindtext \item[Do.\ 03.04.\ 10:00--18:00] 
\blindtext \item[Fr.\ 04.04.\ 10:00--12:00] 
\blindtext 
\end{description}
\end{minipage}}
\clearpage % end the column
\mbox{}
\clearpage % end the spanned column
\section{Danksagung} Ich danke mir! 
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I would need the double page after the welcome page with the image, where Programm starts. I tried to fiddle around with your code but I only got it overlapping. Via `\makebox` you create the double column, I think I got that so far. With `\minipage`you fill that box I guess. Why is that necessary? I seem to be missing the part where you define the last page as empty. If you could elaborate a tad more on what you did, that would be great!

Comment: @idkfa The `\makebox` is for making TeX think the text fits in a column; inside it the minipage sets the width of its contents two twice the line width (plus some eye computed intercolumn space). I added another version, hoping it's what you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. From what I see you took two different approaches here. The `\mbox` for keeping the spanned`Text together makes sense. As for your first version, since I want to understand everything,  how do did you fool leaflet into thinking the last page is empty? Simply by using the 2 column text and not using it? I hope I understood everything so far.

Comment: @idkfa The last page is filled automatically, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

One can also create leaflets using flowframe.  It isn't as easy, but creating an extra wide page is trivial.  I wasn't sure if the fourth or fifth page was supposed to be the wide one.

Remove the asterisks to stop showing the frame edges.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1in}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\columnsep}
\divide\mywidth by 3

\newflowframe*[1]{\mywidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe*[1]{\mywidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \mywidth + \columnsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe*[1]{\mywidth}{\textheight}{\dimexpr 2\mywidth + 2\columnsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe*[2]{\dimexpr 2\mywidth + \columnsep}{\textheight}{\dimexpr \mywidth + \columnsep}{\textheight}
\newflowframe*[2]{\mywidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{\textheight}

\setflowframe{4,5}{angle=180}

\begin{document} 
First page
\newpage
Second Page
\newpage
Third page
\newpage
Fourth Page
\newpage
Fifth page
\end{document}
```

Comment: The fifth should be the wide one. I looked up your commands and was able to switch pages. So far it looks really promising. I'll try and insert my content, headers and everything else I need and see if I can get a long with flowframe.