# Fold paper lengthwise into a booklet

Tags: pdfpages, double-sided, printing

I have a pdf named `prebooklet.pdf` that is *n* pages long and I want to create a booklet that folds lengthwise. The `prebooklet.pdf` uses `\usepackage[paperwidth=80mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry}` to ensure the text does not span to wide.

When adding the pages together using `\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x1]{prebooklet.pdf}` the order of the pages become wrong in the purpose of folding the printed copy. However by adding the `booklet` or `signature` command to fix this, the pages are placed above one and eachother in a fashion that is not desired in this case. (It would be if `prebooklet.pdf` was in the format of an A5-paper and I wanted to fold it sideways.) See visual representation further down. As a final output, four of the pages in `prebooklet.pdf` will be printed on a single sheet of paper and repeated until all of the pages in `prebooklet.pdf` are covered.

There are plenty of related articles regarding inserting A5-paper into an A4-paper and folding it into a booklet, however I was unable to find a method regarding this issue.

Code for creating `prebooklet.pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=80mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Code for creating booklet

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x1]{prebooklet.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x1,booklet]{prebooklet.pdf}
\end{document}
```

In short I want the pages arranged like this
[source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60934/how-to-sort-the-order-of-pages-so-that-they-can-be-printed-in-a-folded-book)

```
      /|=====>>/|=====>>/|
  n->/ | n-2->/ | n-4->/ |
    /  |     /  |     /  |
   /n-1|    /n-3|    /n-5|
   |\  |    |\  |    |\  |
   | \ |    | \ |    | \ |
   |  \     |  \     |   |
   |   |    |   |    |   |
   | 1 |    | 3 |    | 5 |
    \  |     \  |     \  |
     \ |<-2   \ |<-4   \ |<-6
      \|=====>>\|=====>>\|
```

[image: (left) Without booklet (center) With booklet (right) Desired result]
(left) Without booklet (center) With booklet (right) Desired result

Comment: If this is being printed on a single sheet of paper, you can use flowfram to order/locate the columns.  A somewhat related example is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248182/number-of-pages-in-leaflet/248248?s=8|0.0595#248248

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to achieve this is by hard-coding the order of the pages. While not recommended it is a solution until an easier one is found. Take for example a document that is eight pages long. The code for creating booklet will in that case be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={8,1,2,7,6,3,4,5},nup=2x1]{prebooklet.pdf}
\end{document}
```