# How to change layout locally?

Tags: tcolorbox, multicol, pdfpages

I want to integrate the corrected exercises into a document.
I would like these corrections to be inserted in reduced size (4 pages on one page) without carrying out post processing.
Is there a package that allows compiling to change the layout?

I specify, the integrated corrector is not compiled, it is integrated as an external file in .tex format and not pdf.
in fact I am looking for the equivalent of pdfpages for .tex files

I think I found an "original" solution that needs to be improved and tested.
The idea is to combine the use of tcolorbox and multicols.

How to ensure that all boxes are the same size, that the distribution of boxes is homogeneous?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

\lipsum[1-3]
\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
width=\textwidth, height=\textheight,scale=0.5,
    enhanced, 
    breakable,
    frame hidden,
    overlay broken = {
        \draw[line width=0.5mm, red, rounded corners]
        (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);},
    ]{}
    \lipsum[1-30]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{multicols}
\clearpage
\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you tagged this `pdfpages` did you read the manual for the package `pdfpages`?

Comment: pdfpages only handles pdf (it seems to me). In my case the corrected to integrated is not yet compiled, it is a .tex file

Comment: That is not obvious from your question please rephrase

Comment: The flowfram package can divide the text area into 4 pages, and geometry can expand the text area.  The big problem will be shrinking the text.  (I miss \magstep.)

Comment: Except for `beamer` document class, where you can make 4x1 handouts, I do not see the point of avoid post-processing with pdfpages, some tool as pdfnup, or from the printer menu, that are all trivial and do not need to touch the source .tex.  AFAIK, there are no packages to do this automatically in other class. Of course, with flowfram, minipages, or simply two columns and a reduced font, you can simulate print 4 pages into one, but for what this mess?

Comment: @John , do you have an example of using flowfram

Comment: Not for this purpose, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512455/two-column-with-a-text-box-in-the-center-wrapping-on-both-sides/512480?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C33.6888#512480 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248182/number-of-pages-in-leaflet/248248?r=SearchResults&s=26%7C10.5668#248248 are similar.

Comment: I offered a solution in the question, please comment